# Ignore dependend jar version in gradle build

Tags: java, jar, filesystems, version, build.gradle

In my project I have a compilation dependency to a jar at the sonatype repsitory that in turn depends on a jar that I only have as a local copy in my filesystem.

To access both jars my build.gradle looks as follows:

```py
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: './3rdparty/mrcp4j/lib', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile group: 'net.sourceforge.halef', name: 'cairo-client', version: '0.1-SNAPSHOT'
}
```

Now, the pom of the cairo-client jar that I pull from sonatype contains a reference to version 0.2 of the mrcp.jar as follows

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mrcp4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>mrcp4j</artifactId>
    <version>0.2</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

The suppliers of the cairo-client.jar did not publish the mrcp4j.jar as thirdparty or similar but seemed to be relying on a copy in their local maven repository.

The build fails because gradle is not able to match the specified version to the one that I am able to provide.

```xml
Could not find org.mrcp4j:mrcp4j:0.2.
  Searched in the following locations:
    https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/mrcp4j/mrcp4j/0.2/mrcp4j-0.2.pom
    https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/mrcp4j/mrcp4j/0.2/mrcp4j-0.2.jar
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/mrcp4j/mrcp4j/0.2/mrcp4j-0.2.pom
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/mrcp4j/mrcp4j/0.2/mrcp4j-0.2.jar
    https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/mrcp4j/mrcp4j/0.2/mrcp4j-0.2.pom
    https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/mrcp4j/mrcp4j/0.2/mrcp4j-0.2.jar
Required by:
  org.jvoicexml:org.jvoicexml.implementation.mrcpv2:0.7.8 > net.sourceforge.halef:cairo-client:0.1-SNAPSHOT
  org.jvoicexml:org.jvoicexml.implementation.mrcpv2:0.7.8 > net.sourceforge.halef:cairo-sip:1.0-SNAPSHOT
```

Is it possible to specify a version for a jar in the file system or to ignore the requested version number and replace the requested attributes?

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime, I was able to find a workaround for that situation. I am sharing it here in the hope that it will be useful for others. Anyway, I am interested in improvements to this.

My workaround is based on ignoring the dependent jar in all configurations and keep the reference to the local one in the file system.

So all I did was adding the following lines

```
configurations.all {
    exclude group: ' org.mrcp4j', module:'mrcp4j'
}
```

The dependency to the file system has to remain to provide the jar.